# Looping over many variables with the same prefix in their name

Tags: stata, prefix, local-variables

I have many variables starting by the same prefix `grado`.

I would like to keep an observation when at least one of these variable equals a certain value, say `4`. Elements of the variables `grado*`are byte.

I have created a local and looped over its elements to create a dummy taking value `1` when at least one of the `grado*`variables is `4`. However, although this runs without error it does not change the value of my dummy to `1` when the condition is satisfied — so basically nothing happens.

See below the code I have used:

```
local A grado*
generate dummy = 0

foreach y of local A{
    replace dummy = 1 if `y' ==4
}
```

My input data looks like this:

```
col1 grado1 grado2
 3     6      4
 4     4      4
 2     4      8      
 4     7      2
```

I would like to obtain the following output:

```
col1 grado1 grado2 dummy
 3     6      4      1
 4     4      4      1
 2     4      8      1
 4     7      2      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am surprised at the claim that this runs without error, as your code is illegal. As an amplified example shows,

```
clear 
input grado1 grado2 
0 4 
1 1 
end 

local A grado*
generate dummy = 0

foreach y of local A { 
    display "`y'" 
    replace dummy = 1 if `y' == 4
}
```

your loop is a loop over a single item `grado*` -- as putting a wildcard into a `local` doesn't unpack the wildcard. So the pertinent part of the code becomes

```
if grado* == 4
```

which produces an error message. I can only guess that you did something different.

Notice that this works

```
gen dummy = 0

foreach y of varlist grado* { 
    display "`y'" 
    replace dummy = 1 if `y' == 4
}
```

as does this one-liner

```
egen wanted = anymatch(grado*), value(4)
```

Comment: for each y of *varlist*  grado*, Thank you varlist was what I needed to make my loop work.

Answer (score 1):

Please look more into the structure of `foreach` loops and local macros:

```
local A grado*

foreach y of varlist `A' {
    replace dummy = 1 if `y' == 4
}
```